# How to make Elasticsearch Agg query based on current agg?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

my docs looks like this

```
{ cool_things: [{ name, id }, { name, id }] }
```

How would I find the id of the one I'm currently in the aggregate. For example this is the query I'm working with.

```
params.body.aggs = {
    uniqueCoolThings: {
      terms: {
        field: 'cool_things.name.keyword'
      },
      aggs: {
        value: {
          top_hits: {
            size: 1,
            _source: {
              includes: ['cool_things.id', 'cool_things.name.keyword']
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Yet this will return

```
...hits._source: {
    uniqueCoolThings: [
        {
            "id": 500,
            "name": "Bob Sagget"
        },
        {
            "id": 501,
            "name": "Matt Damon"
        }
     ]
} ...
```

I'm wondering how to do a where condition so that it will only return the ID that matches the unique cool_things.name.keyword it is currently on.

I need to get a list of all unique_cool things, and then have their ID's come back with that response (if that makes sense)

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!!

Comment: If you make `cool_things` of type `nested` then this would work

Comment: Could you give me a sudo code example? Sry, just started learning ES :)

Comment: I think Val is referring to a [nested aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).  In order to do that, you would need to update the field mapping to be `nested` as well, which is covered in that docs page I linked to.